# Finite basis for the equational identities of the conditional operator

Tags: universal-algebra

Consider the structure $(\{0,1\}, *)$, where $*$ represents the conditional operator in logic, defined by $1*1=0*0=0*1=1$ and $1*0=0$. Is there a finite basis for the equational identities of that algebraic structure, and if so, can someone exhibit a finite list of identities?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From **R. Lyndon, Identities in two-valued calculi, Trans Amer Math Soc 71 (1951), 457-465,**
we know that every 2-element algebraic structure in a finite language has a finite basis of equational identities.

From **J. C. Abbott, Implicational algebras, Bulletin mathématique de la Société des Sciences Mathématiques de la République Socialiste de Roumanie
Nouvelle Série, Vol. 11 (59), (1967), 3-23**, we know an explicit basis of equational identities for the 2-element implication algebra $\langle \{0,1\}; \to \rangle$:

$((x\to y)\to x) = x$,

$((x\to y)\to y) = ((y\to x)\to x)$,

$(x\to (y\to z))=(y\to (x\to z))$.